# Unsupported lookup 'istartwith' for CharField or join on the field not permitted

Tags: python, django

I created some models using Django ORM.

```
class feed(models.Model):
    location = models.OneToOneField('feedlocation')

class feedlocation(models.Model):
    areaHash = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
```

Then I used the follow code to find out the 'feed' on the same areaHash.

```
Feed.objects.filter(location__areaHash__istartwith='*****')
```

The I got this error:

```
FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'istartwith' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.
```

What should I do to achieve this query?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This code is incorrect :

```
Feed.objects.filter(location__areaHash__istartwith='*****')
```

Try :

```
Feed.objects.filter(location__areaHash__istartswith='*****')
```

Comment: It is the same error "Unsupported lookup 'startwith' for CharField or join on the field not permitted"

Comment: Check its startswith not startwith

Comment: oh! Thanks! I am foolish. Orz.

Comment: I am glad it helped .. You may like accept the answer too :)

Comment: But the OP wanted a case-insensitive lookup, and this answer loses that ability.

Comment: Ok, so it's just a typo, missing 's' from the starts

Answer (score 2):

Another Workaround could be using icontains (keeping case-insensitivity as @shacker noticed) :

```
Feed.objects.filter(location__areaHash__icontains='*****')
```

Comment: This seem the correct answer even if check if `contains` and not `startswith`